# How to set x-axis ticks at the left of each bar with echarts library?

Tags: javascript, echarts

I want to show each x-axis tick at the left of the bar, not at the center, but I'm not sure which setting can help me with this, I tried setting the `boundaryGap` to false, but no luck. Please notice the x-axis type is `time`.
[image]

http://jsfiddle.net/ztcyhwr9/

Answer (score -1):

```
let xAxis = historyTheft.map(item => moment(item[0]).format('HH:mm'));
let series = historyTheft.map(item => item[1]);

....
option = {
   color: ["#009C95","#21ba45"],
   title : {
       text: 'Fuel History',
       textStyle: {
           fontFamily: 'lato'
       }
   },
   tooltip : {
       trigger: 'axis'
   },
   xAxis: {
       type: 'category',
       data: xAxis
   },
   yAxis : {
       type: 'value'
   },
   series : [
       {
           name:'Fuel Theft',
           type:'bar',
           itemStyle: {normal: {areaStyle: {type: 'default'}}},
           data: series
       }
   ]
}
```

I hope, it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you for your comment :) but my problem is not with the tooltip, I want each x axis tick to appear in at the left of the bars instead of the center I will improve the description

Comment: OK, I got :). You need to modify your `xAxis` data and `series` data. You can look at this example(https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=bar-background)

Comment: Yes, I saw those examples working when the `xAxis` type is `category` but I can't get it working with `time` data. Actually, to be more precise, I want to graph time intervals, for example, today from 00:00 to 00:10, the bar or y value is a value between 0-100, that's why I need the `xAxis` `tick` to appear at the left of the bar and not at the center. Can you modify the jsfiddle I provided if you have any idea of how to solve this? Thank you again :)

Comment: @JuliaSuarez, curious if you've found a solution for this? Have been struggling for a while now with the exact same problem. Feels like it should be something basic and easily doable